# Is there a Chrome extension that will take a screenshot of the whole page?

Tags: gratis, chrome, screenshot

I often like to take screenshots of lists online. They vary by size and purpose, but it's a pain when the section I want to document is longer than my screen. This happens not that often, but it's annoying to have to zoom out to 25% and then take a very low quality screenshot with Greenshot.

What I would like:

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- Chrome Extension (obviously)
- Takes a screenshot of the page. A select only part of the page would be useful, but not required by any means
- Simple, and easy to use
- Lightweight; no need to slow computer down

Although this feature is a very far stretch, it'd be ***amazing*** if it had built in support with Greenshot. However, that doesn't seem to be possible, as it won't open a file as a standard image editor. I hope that you prove me wrong on this point :)

Comment: So, basically, you want to capture a so-called "scrolling area", am I right?

Comment: Maybe converting the whole page to pdf? http://www.web2pdfconvert.com/

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I use [Nimbus Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nimbus-screenshot/bpconcjcammlapcogcnnelfmaeghhagj).

Right click on the page, select `Nimbus Screenshot` then `Entire Page`.

- [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- Available for Chrome
- Works also for `Selected area`
- Rather simple, even though I could do without the edition window it shows after screenshot is taken
- Did not notice any slowliness

Answer (score 9):

One is **[Awesome Screenshot: Capture & Annotate](http://awesomescreenshot.com/)**

1. Capture or clip selected area, or all visible portion, or entire page
2. Support  PNG format
3. Support  horizontal scroll when capturing
4. Annotate it with rectangles, circles, arrows, lines and text
5. Crop and scroll & Show crop area dimension
6. Use eraser to hide sensitive information
7. Copy the screenshot  and paste it to GMail etc. Support Windows and Linux.
8. Save to Local
9. One-click to [upload](http://awesomescreenshot.com/) and get a shareable link
10. Support Google Drive (Gdrive) Now.
11. Save very large image, bypass the 2Mb limit. No crash any more.

[image]

Comment: This is a malicious extension. I wrote a post about it a while ago: http://gaboverflow.wordpress.com/2014/01/07/why-you-should-not-use-chrome-extensions/

Comment: And the "Capture Entire Page" option doesn't work for me, while other extensions do work

Comment: @nidunc, well it works for me so can't say anyting about it... :)

Comment: @Gabriel, thanks dude, i was not knowing about this fact. Thank u so much for that.

Answer (score 5):

Unlike what the name suggests,

### [FireShot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/capture-webpage-screensho/mcbpblocgmgfnpjjppndjkmgjaogfceg)

is available for Google Chrome (also for Firefox and even Internet Explorer).

- It's a [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis) Chrome extension. It has a Pro version, but you probably won't need that.
- You can take a screenshot

  - Of the whole page
  - Of a selection
  - Of the visible area
  - Of the whole screen, including the Windows taskbar and the Chrome toolbars.

  [image: FireShot Chrome capture menu]
  *FireShot button menu - also integrates with the right-click menu*
  [image: context menu]
- It's simpler than the [Firefox version](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/4480/2437) (less settings for the extension - Editor settings are the same), and quite straightforward.
- It doesn't noticeably slow your computer down (around 30MB RAM and less than 0% CPU usage when idle)

---

- You can edit the screenshots afterwards in the built-in editor
  [image: editor toolbar]
  or you can open it in an external program, but I don't know if Greenshot supports this.
  Well, there's no harm in trying.
  [image: Open in external Program dialog]
- You can also directly upload them to a service.
  [image: supported upload services]

Comment: I did notice that Greenshot has *some* capability to open files, although I don't know how well it'll work with FireShot. Thanks though, I'll take a look and see if it works. If it does, I'll post how I did it here.

Comment: @AnnonomusPenguin It's more than one week later, so I assume it didn't work.

Comment: I tried but I couldn't find a way to open it from source using the command line. There's a menu option when you right click the Greenshot icon in the try that says `open from file`. I never figured out the command line, though.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT** (2014-08-23): Webpage Screenshot now adds their URLs a the bottom left of the screenshot, thereby making the screenshot unnecessarily wider, so I advise against it.

---

You can use the Chrome Extension [Webpage Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki/related?hl=en):

- Free
- Chrome Extension
- Simple, and easy to use
- Takes a screenshot of the entire page, or only the visible part.
- Lightweight
- Editor to post-process

[image]

PS: I used to use [Screen Capture (by Google)](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/reviews?hl=en) and [Pixlr Grabber](http://support.pixlr.com/pixlr/topics/isnt_grabber_still_available_for_ie_or_chrome) but they both stopped working recently.

Comment: *Unrelated* You have a whole lot of extensions

Answer (score 2):

#### [Webpage Screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/webpage-screenshot/ckibcdccnfeookdmbahgiakhnjcddpki)

- Is [gratis](/questions/tagged/gratis)
- Is a Chrome extension
- You can take a screenshot of either the entire page, or just the visible area, but you can crop the screenshot afterwards with the built-in editor
  [image: Screenshot menu]
- Fairly simple and easy to use
- Doesn't slow the computer down; lightweight

You can edit screenshots after capturing with the built-in editor that automatically appears.
[image: Built-in editor]
As you can see, you can also share the screenshots to numerous social networking and file storage websites/services.

---

If you want an extension that simply captures the whole screen with just one mouse click

#### [Full Page Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/full-page-screen-capture/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl)

should be perfect for you.
[image: Full Page Screen Capture menu]
After capturing it shows the screenhot in a new tab, where you can save it or copy it through the right-click menu. There are no built-in editing or sharing features, it's a very basic add-on which does what it's supposed to do.

Answer (score 1):

[Fullscreenrrr - full webpage screenshot](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fullscreenrrr-full-webpag/ihaobgceoogckalioenpheioedgjaahk)

[image]

- Very simple and easy to use
- Up to 50% faster than other extensions,
- After Screenshoot completion - images are saved directly on Downloads folder
- Shows in percents the current progress
- You can hear during the capture process, capture feedback with camera analog click sound

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### You don't need an extension because Chrome offers a built-in Full Page Screenshot feature

First, we need to open DevTools inside Chrome. We can open it in different ways:

- Main Menu (⋮ three vertical dots) in the top-right corner > More tools > Developer tools.
- Keyboard shortcuts: <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Windows and Linux, or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> in Mac.
- Right-clicking anywhere in the page and select Inspect.

From there, there are multiple ways to capture a full page screenshot.

My preferred way (see https://superuser.com/a/1218097/74576 and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=r_6_9eFPhxI):

1. Toggle the device toolbar
2. Set the desired resolution in the device toolbar
3. Select the More options overflow menu in the device toolbar
4. Select Capture screenshot or Capture full size screenshot
5. The screenshot will be saved to your Downloads folder

For another way, see https://medium.com/better-programming/how-to-take-full-page-screenshots-in-chrome-without-extensions-be2f0cf36df1.