# Linux-based Screen Capture program?

Tags: linux, screenshot

So I've been using greenshot on windows and it is great, I've recently made the switch to linux and I need a screenshot program that is 'up to par' with greenshot.

Comment: Most people don't know the app you're talking about, me neither. Remove the app name and just detail all features you want.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul Program. Not an app. But for anyone who doesn't know what Greenshot is, I recommend a visit to http://getgreenshot.org/.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel: It is possible for a piece of software to be both a "program" and an "application" - what makes you say that this software is not an app?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel that's not how this site works – see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185). And besides, **Quantum88:** Did you ever use our nice search function? We already have [16 questions with answers]([How to ask for an alternative to some software](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/48/185)) for Linux screenshot tools. Also, please follow the first link in my comment and then update your question accordingly, or it will be closed: requirements **must** be named explicitely here.

Comment: @Izzy Someone's cranky...

Comment: @psmears It's actually quite hard to express myself in this subject. If you want, you can ping me in a chatroom where I can discuss it.

Comment: My [answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/3069/simple-program-to-edit-screenshots-add-texts-and-arrows-mark-stuff-on-linux/21077#21077) also has an alternative, in case there is room for new stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### [Shutter](http://shutter-project.org/)

It would be great if you could supply more details on which specific features you'd like. Lacking that, Shutter comes first to mind. It has many of the features that are present in Greenshot, including:

- Capturing screen regions
- Opening captured image in editor
- Uploading the captured files online

It also has the capability to capture entire webpages by simply entering their URL, though for that I'd recommend a browser extension especially since pages that require registration won't work. Refer to [this question](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/4241/6834) for suggestions about that.

Comment: I've been using that but it's been disappointing thus far,  I guess I haven't configured it enough...

Comment: One feature that is sometimes useful is the option to capture an entire page on Internet Explorer. Since Linux (gladly!) doesn't have such thing, is this possible in other browsers?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel It's independent of the browser. You just need to copy the page address into Shutter

Comment: @Quantum88 It needs a bit more configuration to get it started than Greenshot does, but the core features are very similar.

Comment: Does it use webkit? Blink? KHTML? Or you aren't sure? Also, some pages may require login (e.g.: facebook, gmail, spotify). How would Shutter handle that?

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I don't know which rendering engine it uses and I can't find it in the documentation. It doesn't work with pages that require log in, for that I recommend you use a browser extension such as [Nimbus](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/nimbus-screenshot-app/aecjogkncpbkjfobfnoaiepipllcadhe?utm_source=chrome-ntp-icon) on Chrome

Comment: That would be a great point to add to the answer. It surely would be a feature that, for example, I would miss from Greenshot. (Since I'm forced to use IE, I enjoy that little feature, that saved me a few times)

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel The problems with that are 1) the OP did not specify which features in Greenshot they're after, and I found it pointless to list all features so I just gave a couple examples. 2) It's unlikely for someone asking for a linux software to be after an IE feature, so that feature isn't particularly relevant to the question. However, capturing webpages in general is important. I've updated the answer

Comment: I was only talking about the important stuff, asking about it and explaining that Greenshot implements it on IE. It isn't an IE native feature.

Comment: @IsmaelMiguel I am aware of the "Capture Internet Explorer" function in Greenshot. It isn't native to IE, but it is specific to it. It won't work with other browsers, particularly the ones also available for Linux. If that point is cleared out. I suggest we clean up the comments to save the mods the work.

Comment: The point has been cleared out before I've commented. You're assuming that I think that it will work in other browsers. I was merely asking if this specific feature, that is only available for IE on Greenshot, is available on Shooter or not (regardless of the browser).

Answer (score 3):

I tend to use "xwd" as it is installed on mostly any linux box having a graphical interface. It is a commandline tool. I know your question was "I want a tool like that windows one". So xwd is surely not a pendant to the windows screenshot tool you mentioned but rather an linux-ish alternative.

You can take a screenshot of the entire desktop by doing

```
xwd -root > screen.xwd
```

Which will save the whole screen in the "screen.xwd" file. The "XWD" file format is nativ to xwd. Often you want to convert your screenshot to jpg or png. You can do this by using the ImageMagick tool "convert". Either after having made the .xwd file or in one go:

```
xwd -root | convert - screen.jpg
```

Of course you can also edit/cropt/whatever the screenshot in the most loved graphics editing program in Linux: The Gimp!

```
gimp screen.xwd
```

I guess for uploading the image to any image sharing service there are scripts or tools out there.

Comment: Using just "xwd > screen.xwd" you can pick a window.

Answer (score 2):

The best two options, in my opinion are:

1. GIMP

   Since it's a full editing program, it has all the necessary functions, and creating a screenshot is simply a small function to complement it. [image: Taking a screenshot in GIMP]
2. `xwd`

   This is the standard *X* *w*indow *d*ump utility, so you don't need to install anything. Call it from the command line or a "Run..." dialog, e.g. as `xwd -out dump.xwd` to capture a single window (the cursor will turn into a crosshair), or `xwd -root -out dump.xwd` to capture the entire screen. You can prefix that by `sleep 5 &&`  if you need a 5 second timer to hide the shell window or open a menu that you want to highlight.